# grabbing an encoded array from a file using ajax

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I was trying to grab an encoded array `[{"got":"1235.00","needed":"4350"}]` from a file using this code:

```
function getNewValues(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'get.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("An error ocurred");
        })
    }
```

But the problem is that the only thing I get back in the `return data` is `array( object )`, the problem is that I don't know what's wrong or in which file it went wrong.

generating the encoded array:

```
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=thermometer', 'root', ''); 
  $sql = 'SELECT `got`.`value` AS got, `needed`.`value` AS needed FROM `needed`, `got`'; 
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($result);
  print_r($json);
?>
```

It would be nice if someone has an solution for this because I can't solve it.

Comment: open your PHP file in your browser and you'll easily see what you are getting returned...

Comment: The php file prints `[{"got":"1235.00","needed":"4350"}]` an when i try to grab that using ajax it turn into `array( object )`. I am trying to make a script that will grab new data without refreshing the page. but it wont work :(

Comment: Please show us a `var_dump` of your json array.

Comment: If i run var_dump this is what i get `string(35) "[{"got":"1235.00","needed":"4350"}]"`.

Comment: So it's returning an array, because it IS an array. How are you trying to use `return data;`? More than likely you will need to loop through the array to use it or parse the key/values individually.

Comment: I am tried `var newValues = getNewValues();` and the to get the data i used `got = newValues["got"];` but then it says `TypeError: newValues is undefined`

Comment: @Thaillie Welcome to the world of async data retrieval. Your function likely ends before it can return... Where you currently have `return data`, put your code that deals with `data` there.

Comment: Thank you @LeeTaylor its fixed now. btw how should i end this question?

Comment: I'm happy to add an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the function has finished by the time the data arrives. This is due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX. You need to handle your data *when* it arrives, not assume it has arrived before it has.

```
function getNewValues(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'get.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        // Handle your data here;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("An error ocurred");
    });

 // Attempting to use the data or returning the data here will not work!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Reread your question. Think [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293438/3503285) to a similar question could help.

Once you have executed the prepared statement, something like this could work instead of the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

```
...
$result = $statement->execute();
for ($file_data = array(); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $file_data[] = $row);
```

$file_data is then an associative array of whatever data it is you want.

```
print json_encode($file_data);
```

Comment: I cant get it to work it refuses to run the `fetch_assoc()` command. cant call on object is what i get back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set and return the variable inside the function, not try to return the ajax return value as the function.  In other words, pass the ajax return to a variable to a function variable and then return that. Something like this:

```
function getNewValues(){
   var returnedJSON= $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'get.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        return data;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("An error ocurred");
    })
   return returnedJSON;
    }
```

Comment: I can grab the data using `data[0].got` but the problem now is that i cant get the data further than the `console.log()` the moment i return the data to a new var it says `undefined variable`.

Comment: post what you have when you get `undefined variable`